# Does FCM push notification registration need to be done once or each time the app is opened

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I'm using `PushNotifications` of capacitor for ionic app to send FCM (firebase cloud messages).

The `PushNotifications.register()` is needed to trigger the 'registration' event with the push token. When the 'registration' event received we use `PushNotifications.addListener('registration',())` to get the token and keep it in order to use it to send FCM.

It seems to me these actions need to be done only once, but I saw somewhere that the token is changed from time to time so maybe this is the reason I saw several examples that do this registration each time the app is opened.

What is the right approach? do it once or each time the app is opened?

Comment: Please read the FCM documentation about token freshness. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens#ensuring-registration-token-freshness